# Is this a valid Yaml list? How do I make YamlDotNet read it?

Tags: c#, yaml, yamldotnet

I have old C++ code which manually parses YAML and has a large number of unit tests.  I am converting it over to C# using YamlDotNet.  But one of the features of the old code was that it could handle a bit of variability in the lists.  For example, consider the following list...

```
images:
  - image01.png 
  - image02.png
  - image03.png
```

The old parsing code could handle the case where there is no space between the '-' character and the item.  So it can also read this with no problem.

```
images:
  - image01.png 
  -image02.png
  - image03.png
```

Unfortunately YamlDotNet does not parse this.  I was converting the unit test that specifically verifies this and YamlDotNet throws a YamlDotnet.Core.SemanticErrorException with this message

> While parsing a block collection, did not find expected '-' indicator

But if I then go in and put the space back between the '-' and the "image02.png", it reads the yaml perfectly.

So my questions are

1. Is this technically even valid YAML?  That is, should the list above always cause a fault?  If not, I'll just get rid of the unit test.
2. But if it *is* valid YAML, is there an option I can pass to the YamlDotNet Deserializer to handle it?

Comment: `- image01.png` (with the space) is the string `image01.png` as an array item. `-image02.png` is just the string `-image02.png` (including the dash), and invalidates the document due to its misplacement within the surrounding array context. From the [specs](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/) under section 2.1. Collections: "Block sequences indicate each entry with a dash and space (“`- `”).".

Comment: @pmf You probably should make an answer out of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In YAML,

- `- image01.png` (with the space) encodes the string `image01.png` as an array item, while
- `-image02.png` encodes just the string `-image02.png` (including the dash), and as such invalidates your document due to its misplacement within the surrounding array context.

So, the answer to your questions is: No, it's not valid YAML. See the [YAML specs](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/) under section [2.1. Collections](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#21-collections):

> Block sequences indicate each entry with a dash and space (“`-` ”).

Comment: Chapter 2, the Language Overview, is not the best part of the documentation to refer to as it leaves out details. Actually, when looking at the appropriate exact productions in the spec, you see that it is not true that every block sequence entry does have to start with a dash followed by a space.

Answer (score 2):

What you have there is a sequence in block style YAML, i.e. a `block sequence`, one of the two block collection styles in YAML (the other being the `block mapping`). Calling it a list (or array, or whatever it is loaded as, into your programming language of choice) makes it hard to find the actual description of [block sequences in the documentation](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#821-block-sequences), the first paragraph of which reads:

> A block sequence is simply a series of nodes, each denoted by a leading “-” indicator. The “-” indicator must be separated from the node by white space.
> This allows “-” to be used as the first character in a plain scalar if followed by a non-space character (e.g. “-42”).

The production rules there indicate that the `-` (called a sequence entry indicator) doesn't have to be followed by a space, but only if the following node is empty:

```yaml
images:
  - image01.png 
  -
  - image03.png
```

What also would be valid YAML is:

```yaml
images:
  - image01.png 
   -image02.png
  - image03.png
```

Here the sequence that is the value for key `images` has two elements: the scalar `image01.png -image02.png` and the scalar `image03.png`.

Both the latter example and your required input involve inserting **one** missing space in the input to get correct YAML, so it is difficult for a real YAML parser to give a good suggestion of what is wrong. So I am not surprised the "manual" parsing got this wrong.

Comment: Yeah, we wrote the manual parsing code a long time ago when there weren't that many decent Yaml parsing libraries out there.  I guess we thought we were being smart and fault tolerant by accepting that invalid input.  I am very happy to jettison this in favor or something much better tested.